# Why is double-to-int cast being assigned to a dynamic variable redundant according to ReSharper?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, resharper

I have an assignment to a dynamic viewbag variable, which **has to be** an integer (yes, integer, *without* a fractional part, which breaks the libraries I'm using):

```
ViewBag.Autosubmit = (int)(SomeDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
```

`TimeSpan.TotalSeconds` returns a `double`, and to use it, I'm casting it into an `int`. But ReSharper says that casting to `int` is redundant. If I don't cast, the number stays as a double and my page doesn't work correctly.

Why is ReSharper telling me the cast is redundant?

Comment: Can you try without using the viewbag, simply do something like `double a = 10.0; dynamic d1 = a; dynamic d2 = (int)a;` and see if it tells you the same? Also, which version of ReSharper are you using?

Comment: Resharper shouldn't be giving this warning at all. Seems like a bug. A cast that isn't a simple reference conversion shouldn't be flagged as it can obviously not be redundant as is your case.

Comment: Can't repro. What versions of MVC and R# are you using?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because the cast is redundant as far as c# is concerned.. you are casting it but then putting it into a dynamic, which doesnt care if its an int or a double..

If you explicitly cast it to an int.. like Lasse V. Karlsen mentioned

```
int autoSubmit = (int)(SomeDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
ViewBag.Autosubmit = autoSubmit;
```

I believe the message will then go away.

Comment: "I think this is because the cast is redundant as far as c# is concerned". This affirmation is absolutely wrong. Casting a `Tiger` to `Animal` might be redundant "as far as c# is concerned" in the given context, casting `double` to `int` is *not* redundant in any way; you are creating an absolutely new object, not simply changing the type of the reference. Resharper shouldn't be giving this warning.

Comment: No, its actually not wrong - At that point... as far as resharper can tell.. based on the c# syntax (So "as far as c# is concerned")... the cast is redundant... when passing it to the dynamic is it as far as that snippet is concerned.. redundant..  to make it so that its not redundant you need to be more explicit, you have to let it know what your intent is... It seems that you have taken issue with the way in which I worded my answer, this in itself doesn't make it factually incorrect? Without you giving more information about your intent, how is resharper supposed to know?

Comment: Whichever way you want to dress it, your answer is wrong. A cast that is not a simple reference conversion can not be flagged as redundant because it isn't, simple as that. This case makes it obvious, I'm not sure what you are trying to discuss here, the code is prefectly fine, the warning isn't. It's not anyone's job to make Resharper's life easier; it should be smart enough to know when a cast is not a simple reference conversion, if it's not then it is a bug or false positive, whatever you like to name it.

Comment: "Why is ReSharper telling me the cast is redundant?" - The answer is the reason why.. it being a bug in resharper or not, I don't care. I am simply pointing out that the answer to asked question is not wrong, that is why resharper throws the warning, your issue with that is valid.. and perhaps it should be a bug in resharper, but that's not question is it? - I will agree to disagree.. but agree with you.. I agree with your point, I disagree that my answer is bad, it answers the question correctly.

Comment: This is going nowhere. Your answer states, and I will quote it again bolding out the relevant part: "*I think this is because the cast **is redundant as far as C# is concerned***". As far as C# is concerned, the cast is most definitely *not* redundant at all, end of story When will the compiler do that conversion for you if it's redundant? What happens if the `double` is boxed and then someone expecting an `int` unboxes it with a direct cast?. Did you mean to say something else? Then rephrase your answer to make it more precise, as it stands now it *conveys* an incorrect message.

Comment: And you should generalize this to any cast. Even if its not a particularly good design, what happens if there is some kind of side effect in a user defined cast operator? Maybe some logging logic, throwing an exception under certain disallowed object states, warning the FBI that someone cast `TopSecretObject`, what have you. The point being, in the general case, a cast can not be considered redundant ever in C# unless you are absolutely sure it is: `Lion simba; object o = (Animal)simba; //Cast to Animal is redundant`.